# Java HTTP Client request set timeout

Tags: java

I want to set the timeout of a request. This is the code, I've got so far.

```
final HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(address);
httppost.setHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(body));
final HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I've tried (does not work, keeps loading and ignores timeout)

```
// set the connection timeout value to 30 seconds (30000 milliseconds)
final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```

and (this one throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`)

```
httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 3000);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 6000);
```

Is there any other way for setting the timout? I don't really need the response so something like an asynchronous request could do the work too.

Comment: isnt this is wrong `final HttpClient httpclient; = HttpClients.createDefault();` you have extra ;

Comment: When you say "does not work", what behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: @JqueryLearner no it's just a copy and paste error.

Comment: @christopher nothing it keeps loading and loading and blocking the Java thread. In my program I set it to 3 seconds and it still loads after 10 seconds

Comment: Have you tried `CoreConnectionPNames.TIMEOUT`?

Comment: @christopher `.TIMEOUT.` does not exist.

Comment: Apologies. I meant `ConnManagerPNames.TIMEOUT`.

Comment: @christopher then I get again `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache's `HttpClient` has two separate timeouts: a timeout for how long to wait to establish a TCP connection, and a separate timeout for how long to wait for a subsequent byte of data.

[`HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout()`](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpConnectionParams.html#setConnectionTimeout%28int%29) is used for establishing a TCP connection, whereas [`HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout()`](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpConnectionParams.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) is used while waiting for a subsequent byte of data.

```
// Creating default HttpClient
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();

// Setting timeouts
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000);

// Rest of your code
final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(address);
httppost.setHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(body));
final HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```